# I am not getting a “Build failed” rule trigger in Jira for Gitlab pipelines with jobs on “push”

Tags: gitlab-ci, jira

I am running a Jira Cloud instance that is integrated with a Gitlab Cloud (SaaS, no paid subscription) repo using the official tools. I have successfully created several automation rules in Jira, so both apps are well configured and connected, but there is one rule that is not working, it is not being triggered

My goal is to detect in Jira when the pipeline fails in order to change the ticket status

My desired flow is

1. User creates Merge Request
   1.1 Jira detects this event and changes ticket status
   1.2 Pipeline is run for $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' jobs
   1.3 Pipeline finishes (uses feature branch)
   1.4 Jira detects failed status and changes ticket status
2. User merges the MR
   2.1 Jira detects this event and changes ticket status
   2-2 Pipeline is run for $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'main' && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'push' jobs
   2.3 Pipeline finishes (uses main branch after the merge)
   2.4 Jira detects failed status and changes ticket status
   This flow is working except for the last step. I have created the Jira rule for it but the rule is not being triggered. Since the rule trigger is cloned from the 1.4 rule, I am assuming that the problem is that the integration is failing, Gitlab is not publishing the event

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - deploy

build-job:    # This job runs the build stage, which runs on Merge Request creation.
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - echo "Compile complete."

deploy-job:   # This job runs the deploy stage, which runs on Merge into Main branch.
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'main' && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'push'
  script:
    - echo "Deploying the code..."
    - echo "Deploy complete."
    - fakecommand
```

That `fakecommand` is on purpose for forcing the pipeline to fail

I created a rule for logging all build state changes.

You can see in the screenshot that all status changed are being detected but the last one (successful to failed)[image]

Should I modified my pipeline? Should I use another rule trigger in Jira? As you can guess, my goal is to have feedback on the main branch performance after the merge is completed.